# Как на Python преобразовать строку в JSON, если в одном из значений имеются кавычки?

Tags: python, json

Нужно преобразовать строку:

```
'{"geo":"Москва","name":"МГТУ "Станкин" (Московский государственный технологический университет Станкин)","faculty_id":"1130078"}'
```

в JSON.

Проблема заключается в том, что значение параметра "name" содержит слово в кавычках("Станкин"), что приводит к ошибке:

```
a = '{"geo":"Москва","name":"МГТУ "Станкин" (Московский государственный технологический университет Станкин)","faculty_id":"1130078"}'
b = json.loads(a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pars.py", line 6, in <module>
b = json.loads(a)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 11 (char 10)
```

Как корректно преобразовать?

Comment: Ну, наверно, всё-таки не в JSON, а **из** JSON в Python-объекты? Варианта получить корректную строку на вход нету?

Comment: Откуда вы взяли такой "JSON" ? Он не корректно построен, ни один язык программирования его автоматически разобрать не сможет. Наиболее прямой путь - попросить того, кто его формирует делать корректный json, в котором кавычки в данных заэкранированы. Либо парсить его регулярными выражениями самому. только эти выражения должны быть рассчитаны строго на него, например искать все от `"name":` до `,"faculty_id"` и считать это текстом одного поля

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы json корректно распарсился, кавычки в данных должны быть экранированы обратным слешэм - `\"`.

Конкретно для этого примера можно сделать так:

```
a = '{"geo":"Москва","name":"МГТУ "Станкин" (Московский государственный технологический университет Станкин)","faculty_id":"1130078"}'
a = a.replace('"Станкин"', r'\"Станкин\"')
b = json.loads(a)
```

Для общего случая вижу два варианта:

1. Договориться с поставщиком данных, чтобы он предоставлял корректный json
2. Написать парсер для выявления неэкранированных кавычек и исправлять

Comment: Второй пункт- из области фантастики! Как быть если строка содержит и неэкранированные кавычки и запятые?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел различные варианты восстановления "битого" JSON. По подобию [Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) для HTML, но только для JSON. Не стал останавливаться только на питоне, из скрипта всегда можно вызвать внешнюю программу.

Итак, на входе у нас:

```
'{"geo":"Москва","name":"МГТУ "Станкин" (Московский государственный технологический университет Станкин)","faculty_id":"1130078"}'
```

### NodeJS: npm пакет [dirty-json](https://github.com/RyanMarcus/dirty-json), вызываемый из питоновского скрипта

Установка (будем считать, что вы поверхностно знакомы с nodeJS)

```
npm install -S dirty-json
```

Скрипт `dirty-json.json`:

```
"use strict";

/*
Простой скрипт, эксплуатирующий пакет dirty-json
  на вход stdin: не валидный JSON
  получаем в stdout: валидный JSON
*/

const
  fs = require('fs'),
  dJSON = require('dirty-json'),
  stdinBuffer = fs.readFileSync(0) // STDIN_FILENO = 0
  ;

const wrongJSON = dJSON.parse(stdinBuffer.toString());
process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(wrongJSON));
```

Пример использования из консоли:

```
echo '{"geo":"Москва","name":"МГТУ "Станкин" (Московский государственный технологический университет Станкин)","faculty_id":"1130078"}' | node dirty-json.js | jq "."
```

Результат - валидный JSON

```
{
  "faculty_id": "1130078",
  "name": "МГТУ \"Станкин\" (Московский государственный технологический университет Станкин)",
  "geo": "Москва"
}
```

Теперь будем использовать этот скрипт из питона. Файл `correct-json.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Наш невалидный JSON
a = '{"geo":"Москва","name":"МГТУ "Станкин" (Московский государственный технологический университет Станкин)","faculty_id":"1130078"}'

# Обработка через NodeJS
process = Popen(["node", "dirty-json.js"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

# Пишем в stdin
process.stdin.write(a)

# Получаем из stdout
(output, err) = process.communicate()

# Код завершения
exit_code = process.wait()

# Парсим исправленный JSON
b = json.loads(output)
print b
```

На выходе видим распарсенный JSON.