# Парсинг JSON в котором встречаются "кавычки в кавычках"

Tags: python, json

Есть вот такие JSON данные, полученные в результате сохранения словаря:

```
{'id':1, 'name':'Garry \"Hotdog\"'}
```

- **Проблема №1**: такой JSON является не стандартным и его десериализация (`json.loads`) вызывает ошибку так как кавычки одинарные.
- **Проблема №2**: внутри элемента `name` содержатся "кавычки в кавычках", т.е. банальная замена одинарных кавычек на двойные проблему не решает.

Пробовал использовать функцию `json.dumps`, и потом передавать объект в `json.loads`, но почему то возвращается не словарь, а строка.

```
import json
str_json = "{'id':1, 'name':'Garry \"Hotdog\"'}"
dmp = json.dumps( str_json )
jstr = json.loads(dmp)
print(jstr['id'])
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как быстро и без "костелей" разобрать "такой" JSON?

Вот похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772609/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-json-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2), но на него никто не ответил(

Comment: Это не JSON. За неимением другого, цитирую вики: `Строка — это упорядоченное множество из нуля или более символов юникода, заключённое в двойные кавычки.`

Comment: Без костылей никак. Первое, что приходит в голову - считать файл как обычный текст, заменить в нём все вхождения одинарных кавычек на двойные и уже получившуюся строку обработать средствами модуля json. Но более правильный образ действий - применить физическое насилие к автору исходных данных.

Comment: Ну если заменить ' на " и использовать json.loads, возвращается словарь.

Comment: @AlexNasov так и задумано. А вам что нужно чтобы возвращалось?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev замена одинарных на двойные не поможет, так как все равно будет ошибка "кавычек в кавычках".....Сейчас подумал, что я просто могу удалить двойные кавычки при чтении из файла, а вот потом уже заменить одинарные на двойные.

Comment: В приведённом вами примере двойные кавычки экранированы, так что никаких ошибок возникать не должно.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev loads возвращает словарь:

Comment: str_json ='{"id":1, "name":"Garry"}'
jstr = json.loads(str_json)
print(jstr['name'])

Comment: Повторяю: Так и должно быть.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev код выше возвращает словарь, а не строку. Я и хочу понять почему так происходит?

Comment: Потому, что функция `json.loads()` всегда возвращает словарь, так как она должна возвращать словарь.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev код в самом вопросе возвращает строку, а не словарь! в этом и есть суть вопроса

Comment: `json.dumps()` не превращает ваш невалидный json в валидный, он её просто экранирует так, чтобы она стала валидным json'ом из одной строки содержащей невалидный json. А `json.loads()` из получившегося json эту строку извлекает. Я вам сразу написал, либо обрабатывайте сырой текст, либо требуйте от источника данных валидности.

Comment: Из стандарта [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-ru.html): > Строка - коллекция нуля или больше символов Unicode, заключенная в
> двойные кавычки

Comment: 1. ТС, а что если заменить одиночную кавычку `'` на двойную и скормить? 2. Посмотрите [hjson](https://hjson.org/), там вкладка Try. Пример `{'id':1, 'name':'Garry \"Hotdog\"'}` hjson обработал

Comment: ТС, решение найдено, написал в ["тот" вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772609/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-json-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2/868714#868714)

Comment: @Total Pusher, но для меня решение это, то что представил MaxU - оно в одну строку решает мою задачу.

Comment: Я думаю, у вас проблема была не в неправильном JSON, а то, что вы не сумели его вставить в питоновский скрипт, правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте воспользоваться [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
In [14]: import ast

In [15]: s = """{'id':1, 'name':'Garry \"Hotdog\"'}"""

In [16]: d = ast.literal_eval(s)

In [17]: d
Out[17]: {'id': 1, 'name': 'Garry "Hotdog"'}
```

корректный (правильный) JSON:

```
In [18]: print(json.dumps(d))
{"id": 1, "name": "Garry \"Hotdog\""}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!!! Получается библиотека json тут вообще не нужна функция ast.literal_eval преобразует строку в словарь!!! Очень круто)

Comment: @AlexNasov у вас на входе не json. Поэтому не удивительно, что модуль json не работает для такого ввода. Правильный ответ на этот вопрос обязан упомянуть, что если есть возможность, то исправьте место, которое вам данные в неверном формате возвращает, чтобы именно json формат использовался бы.

Comment: ну я же сразу написал, что "такой" json....и я думаю было очевидно, что мне нужно было обработать такие данные, а не исправить их.